# Drupal base URL and root relative paths

Tags: drupal

I changed my Drupal [`$base_url`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) in `settings.php` to

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder
```

but root relative paths are still pointing to

```
http://www.example.com
```

and not to the correct "subfolder". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I flushed cache, re-edited a couple links to make sure but they're still pointing to the root domain and not to the correct subfolder.

Comment: +1, I'm having a similar issue.  Hopefully someone knows the answer!

Comment: You should be more specific about where these paths are...

Answer (score 3):

The [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module provides input filtering to correct URLs that are no longer correct because of configuration changes. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... an input filter which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS feeds. See more example use cases on the documentation page.
>
> Pathologic is designed to be a simple, set-it-and-forget-it utility. You don't need to enter any special “tags,” path prefixes, or other non-content noise into your content to trigger Pathologic to work; it finds paths it can manage in your content automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by root-relative paths. If you are talking about the front paged linked to

```
http://www.example.com
```

you may edit `$base_url` in `settings.php`.

If you are talking about

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

linking to

```
http://www.example.com
```

that has nothing to do with Drupal, though the [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module mentioned by @sutch may help.